# Unable to find proper documentation on Myntra to get products details

Tags: java, node.js, .net

I am working on a project that involves retrieving details of similar products from an uploaded image. I noticed that the Myntra app utilizes a search lens feature for this purpose, but I'm having difficulty finding relevant documentation.

Help me to find the solution using Myntra search lens or any other way.

Comment: Is this a way to advertise an app?